# Scikit-learn: SVM implementation (I obtain a perfect classification)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am new in machine learning and in scikit-learn. I started to use it in order to classify different datasets. For that I started applying scikit-learn's SVC with [this dataset](http://pastebin.com/wxSLhEsB), It's a huge JSON with this a structure similar to this:

```
{"name": "anyName", "tables":
  [
     {"tableName":"dislexia", "datos":[
          {"rasgo1:"0.86 , "rasgo2":45 ... "rasgo61": 2},
            .
            .
            .
          {"rasgo1:"0.3, "rasgo2":5... "rasgo61": 32},
         ]
     },
     {"tableName":"fibro", "datos":[
          {"feature1:"0.86 , "feature2":45 ... "feature61": 2},
            .
            .
            .
          {"feature1:"0.3, "feature2":5... "feature61": 32},
         ]
     }
  ]
}
```

However, I obtain a perfect classification, even if I only train the SVM with 1 data of each type. Can someone tell me why I am obtaining a perfect classification and what I am doing wrong? Shouldn't it have some errors?

**My code:**

```
def prueba3(request):
    from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
    from sklearn import svm, preprocessing
    from sklearn import cross_validation
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.lda import LDA
    from sklearn.qda import QDA
    from sklearn.svm import NuSVC

    listaTrain=[]
    listaLabels=[]
    listaTest=[]

    #I have several JSONs in a NoSQL Database and with this method I obtain them
    proyectos = list(projectCollection.find())
    #Now from the obtained list I search and obtain the JSON which has a field
    #with the value "pruebaClasificadores2"
    proyecto=buscarProyecto(proyectos,"pruebaClasificadores2")

    #The last 2 methods above can be substituted by putting the dropbox's 
    #JSON in the variable "proyecto"

    #From the JSON dataset y search for the JSONs with tableName "dislexia" and "fibro"
    atributo0=buscarAtributo(proyecto,"fibro")
    atributo1=buscarAtributo(proyecto,"artritis")

    #I split the data in the dataset: 25 samples from "dislexia" (its label is 1) 
    #and 25 from "fibro" (its label is 0) go for the "trainingList", 
    #the rest of the samples of both labels go to the "testList"

    contador0=0
    for dato in atributo0["datos"]:
        if contador0<25:
            listaTrain.append(dato)
            listaLabels.append(0)
            contador0+=1
        else:
            listaTest.append(dato)  
    contador0=0
    for dato in atributo1["datos"]:
        if contador0<25:
            listaTrain.append(dato)
            listaLabels.append(1)
            contador0+=1
        else:
            listaTest.append(dato)

    print "lista labels"
    print listaLabels

    vec = DictVectorizer()
    #I transform the trainingList with JSON  components to a usable matrix
    X=vec.fit_transform(listaTrain)
    #I normalize the matrix            
    X=preprocessing.scale(X.toarray())
    #I transform the testList with JSON  components to a usable matrix
    testX=vec.fit_transform(listaTest)
    #I normalize the matrix
    testX=preprocessing.scale(testX.toarray())

    clf1=NuSVC()
    #I train the classifier
    trained1=clf1.fit(X,listaLabels) 

    #I send the testList to the classifier
    predicted1=clf1.predict(testX)

    print
    print "NuSVC"
    print predicted1 #I display the predicted labels of the classifier

    #I count the number of labels of type 0 and 1 and display them
    fibro1=0
    artritis1=0
    for pos in range(0,len(predicted1)):
        if (predicted1[pos]==0):
            fibro1+=1
        else:
            artritis1+=1

    print "fibro1"
    print fibro1
    print "artritis"
    print artritis1

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/tecnico/')

def buscarAtributo(proyecto,atributoC):
    encontrado=False
    atributos=proyecto["atributos"]
    for a in range(0,len(atributos)):
        atributo=atributos[a]
        if atributo["nombreAtributo"]==atributoC:
            atrib=atributo
            encontrado=True
    if encontrado:
        return atrib
    else:
        print "no se ha encontrado el atributo"
```

Comment: How are you assessing that it's perfect?

Comment: In the input i put 4 (for example) objects which should belong to 0, 0, 1 and 1 (in that order) labels and in the output I obtain the array of [0,0,1,1]

Comment: But it's doing this for lots of data correct, not just four?

Comment: yes, in the dataset i have 2 groups: the first group has 53 samples and the second one 74

Comment: Do you think it's possible that they are VERY easy to classify?  EG the data is very well separated or something?  What if you add a few spurious data points that don't fit the mold?  Do they still get classified correctly?

Comment: The thing is that doing this in Matlab I obtain an output with errors and here i don't and i can't see why

Comment: If you only have 53+74 samples, can you just post them on dropbox and we can quickly answer your question with real data?  There are two or three possibilities... either you are including your solution feature in the input, one of your features is a direct linear proxy for the solution, or you have a really easy problem and the classifier works well on it. Thanks!

Comment: Here you have the link with the dataset in the JSON format: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/uigyp0ph64ix03t/AAC_X9MM-Sv1AzkpeC79Qeqma?dl=0) . I forgot to say that each sample has 61 features (i don't know if it means if it is easy to classify or hard) and thanks to you!

Comment: Can you put your real code in here, its missing imports for the libraries you are using.  Also, you have weird indentation in part of the code and // is not a python comment (use #)

Comment: Ok, I have just put the code

Comment: What classifier and parameters did you use in Matlab?

Comment: There is also an issue in your feature extraction and scaling: You can do fit_transform on your training set, but you should only use transform on your test set, otherwise you don't apply the same transformations on both training and test. Same with the scaling, use a `StandardScaler` instance and fit_transform on training, transform on test dataset.